# Config global user name and email differently for two Git versions on same computer

Tags: git, git-config

I have Git installed on my Windows machine and I also have portable git version in folder `D:\portableGit` on the same machine. I would like that these two versions act independently so that each one have its own config. Currently somehow they share the same config.

For example when I change email  from portable version via

```
git config --global user.email "MyEmailAddressForPortableVersion"
```

it changes email address also for non-portable git version and vice versa.

I tried to set git HOME folder for portable version hoping that git will store config in that folder. I did that by adding `HOME="/myconfig` line in `D:\portableGit\etc\profile` file and now it looks like

```
....
HOME="/myconfig"
# normalize HOME to unix path
HOME="$(cd "$HOME" ; pwd)"
....
```

I also create `D:\portableGit\myconfig` folder, but still both git version share the same global config data.

Comment: Can you try to use --local or --system option instead of --global, because global generally sets values in config file available for windows logged in user

Comment: It is possible to use --local, but then I need to config every repository, which is not very good solution for me. I was thinking that --global should set values in config file for windows user, but global in portable version should set values in config file inside some portable directory like /usr folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, you can call Git by opening `git-bash.exe` or `git-cmd.exe` depending whether you want to start Git in bash or in cmd.

**Depending what you start, Git can search for config file in different location.**

To change the path you can do the following:

### **If you are using `git-bash`**:

You can alter `$HOME` variable in `pathToGit\etc\profile` file by adding `HOME="/myconfig` and then Git will search in `pathToGit\myconfig` for `.gitconfig` file where global config settings are stored, exactly as I describe in the question.

### **If you are using `git-cmd`**:

You need also to change `%HOME%` but not in `etc\profile` file. In portable version open file `git-cmd.bat`, find two lines which looks like

```
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

and remove it. Then define `HOME` variable inside `git-cmd.bat` in the following way

```
set HOME=%git_install_root%\myconfig
```

if you want that Git search for config file in `pathToGit\myconfig` folder.